# JavaScript - Function que altera o background do elemento pai

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Estou com dificuldades ao fazer uma function. Podem me ajudar? 
Após clicar no checkbox ou em cima da label, ele colore somente a palavra, gostaria que colorisse também o background da div, tentei fazer um script como: 
`var obj = document.getElementById("teste").parent();
 obj.style.backgroundColor='#FF0000';` 
Porém não deu certo, podem me ajudar??

```js
    function teste(){
       var obj = document.getElementById("categoria").parent();
         obj.style.backgroundColor='#FF0000'; 
    }
```

```css
input.check-genero:hover + label,
input.check-genero:checked + label{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

/* Tabela conteúdo */
table.tabela-categoria{
    border: solid 15px #fff;
}

.tabela-categoria td{
    border: solid 2px #d3d1d1;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 140px;
}

.categoria + label{
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #727176;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.categoria:hover + label,
.categoria:checked + label{
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color:#FF6600;
}
```

```html
<table class="tabela-categoria">
    <tr>
        <td class="tabela-categoria">
            <input type="checkbox" name="cont1" id="animais" class="categoria">
            <label for="animais" onclick="teste()">ANIMAIS</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cont2" id="artes" class="categoria">
            <label for="artes">ARTES</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cont3" id="beleza" class="categoria">
            <label for="beleza">BELEZA</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cont4" id="business" class="categoria">
            <label for="business">BUSINESS</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cont5" id="causas" class="categoria">
            <label for="causas">CAUSAS</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cont6" id="comedia" class="categoria">
            <label for="comedia">COMEDIA</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Vc está usando document.getElementById("categoria") mas não existe nenhum elemento no seu HTML com a id categoria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passa o evento para essa função e depois faz `e.target.closest('td')` para encontrar o `td`.

Exemplo:

```js
function teste(e) {
  var el = e.target.closest('td');
  el.style.backgroundColor = '#FF0000';
}
```

```css
input.check-genero:hover+label,
input.check-genero:checked+label {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}


/* Tabela conteúdo */

table.tabela-categoria {
  border: solid 15px #fff;
}

.tabela-categoria td {
  border: solid 2px #d3d1d1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 140px;
}

.categoria+label {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #727176;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.categoria:hover+label,
.categoria:checked+label {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #FF6600;
}
```

```html
<table class="tabela-categoria" onclick="teste(event)">
  <tr>
    <td class="tabela-categoria">
      <input type="checkbox" name="cont1" id="animais" class="categoria">
      <label for="animais" >ANIMAIS</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="cont2" id="artes" class="categoria">
      <label for="artes">ARTES</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="cont3" id="beleza" class="categoria">
      <label for="beleza">BELEZA</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="cont4" id="business" class="categoria">
      <label for="business">BUSINESS</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="cont5" id="causas" class="categoria">
      <label for="causas">CAUSAS</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="cont6" id="comedia" class="categoria">
      <label for="comedia">COMEDIA</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Entendi @Sergio !!, vou estudar e aplicar o ensinamento, obrigado !!

Comment: teria como fazer isso com o css? por exemplo : `.categoria:has(td a:hover){`

Comment: @Sora o CSS não tem seletores para ancestrais. Conforme o nome `cascading` ele só aplica a descendentes e elementos irmãos.

Comment: Entendo, obrigado pela explicação !!

Answer (score 1):

Com o document.getElementById("categoria") você está procurando por um elemento com id categoria mas ela não existe no seu html, você precisa procura por um elemento com a classe categoria. Para isso você pode usar querySelector pois ele procura por classes no html, além de ids. Veja no código abaixo, testei e funcionou.

```
function teste(){
  var obj = document.querySelector(".categoria").parentNode;
  obj.style.backgroundColor='#FF0000'; 
}
```

O método .parent() também não funciona pois é do jQuery, com JS puro use parentNode.

Comment: Aaah, entendi !! muito obrigado :D

Comment: Teria como fazer com css através do `.categoria:has(td a:hover){`  ?
Este has parece que também pode servir e bem melhor, pois resolve tudo pelo css

Comment: O :has é uma pseudo-classe do css mas ainda está em teste, não use por enquanto. 
Veja nesse site, na tabela de compatibildiade dos browsers:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

Aqui também, nenhuma compatibilidade com os navegadores:
https://caniuse.com/#search=%3Ahas

Comment: Entendo, obrigado